Как получить изображения, не распознанные в тестовом датасете, при осуществлении оценки обученной модели?
Используя "TensorFlow 2 Object Detection API" мы можем создать и обучить детекторную нейромодель ==> TensorFlow 2 Object Detection API tutorial
В этом API также существует метод для оценки качества обученной модели ==> Evaluating the Model 
Эта оценка позволяет получить данные Average Precision/Average Recall.
Можно ли как-то получить список изображений, которые были не распознаны в тестовом датасете, при выполнении Evaluating?
